# C++ simple threads example

Tags: c++, multithreading

Hello I'm studying c++ & threads.I'm new to c++ and the following code is my own based on experience in other languages. However although to me it seems okay and it does compile, when I execute it, it hangs - does nothing. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread> 
#include <vector>
#include <string> 

void printLine(std::string str) {   
    std::cout << str << std::endl; 
}

void child(int id) {    
    printLine("This is a thread with id: " + std::to_string(id)); 
}

int main() {

    printLine("This is the main thread and we are baout to spawn threads...");      
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        threads[i] = std::thread(child, i);         
        threads[i].join();

    }

    printLine("Press any key to exit...");  
    std::getchar();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Out of bounds access so undefined behaviour: `threads[i] = std::thread(child, i); `. The vector `threads` is empty.

Comment: why are you "adding" the threads to a vector when you're not using them outside of the for loop?

Comment: For people down-voting and feel that this is a stupid question, I would appreciate it if you could at least provide a reference regarding my error instead down-voting.

Answer (score 1):

Your code trying to get some threads running isn't the problem here, it's with the test case:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    threads[i] = std::thread(child, i);         
    threads[i].join();

}
```

`threads` is empty upon entering the `for` loop, thus accessing `threads[0]` or > 0 leads to Undefined Behaviour.

You should use `push_back` ( or `emplace_back` ) instead to actually add elements to that `vector`:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    threads.push_back(std::thread(child, i));         
    threads[i].join();
}
```

Comment: @Juanchopanza True, I tried to focus on the part that's causing UB rather than the actual sense of the code.